# bootstrap carousel image height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm having some problems with the images in bootstrap v4 image carousel. If i scale down the browser width the height of image stays the same but the width of image getting smaller so the image gets very stretched out on the height.

I have been looking at similar threads here on stackoverflow and tried everything i found in the comments but it still does not work. So i decided to make a new thread about this.

Here is a codepen link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owNyyx but i paste the code here too if you do not wish to visit codepen :)

So here is the code i have

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/image1.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Random Title for image1</h3>
        <p>Random description1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/image2.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Random title for image2</h3>
        <p>Random description2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="images/image3.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Random title for image3</h3>
        <p>Random description3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can write a window resize event to set the height property to image tag as per the aspect ration and window current width. I did that for one my project.

Comment: You mean to use @media rule in css? Or to use some javascript event?

Comment: you can use @media  but you have to write too much css. If you want best result go window.onresize = function(event) {}; if you use jQuery  then $(window).resize(function(){//your code here});

Comment: Alright thanks. I will try that

Comment: I have one code ready with me, but it is not accessible to me right now. I will post as soon as I get access to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the img parent, `.carousel-item` is `display: flex` and the `img` is a flex-child, so it's "stretching" via the default `align-items: stretch` on the parent.

A number of ways you can fix this. Easiest is probably to give `align-items` a value other than `stretch`.

Or if you don't want to apply custom CSS and keep your changes in the markup, wrap each `img` in a block element like `div` or `figure` or whatever works for your site.

```css
.carousel-item {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/500" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Cheap prizes for hairstyling</h3>
        <p>Good prizes to style your hair</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/500/cats/2" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>3 Years of experience as Hairstylist</h3>
        <p>Awesome results !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1900/500/cats/3" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Some random caption text</h3>
        <p>Some random description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @TimLevinsson you're welcome. Took me a minute to figure it out! Good question, I think this will be useful to people in the future since the bootstrap docs for carousel have `img`s as the child of `.carousel-item`. So I think this will come up fairly regularly for folks.